# Alpha conversion on a Haskell expression

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, haskell-src-exts

Given a Haskell expression, I'd like to perform alpha conversion, ie. rename some of the non free variables.

I've started implementing my own function for this, which works on a haskell-src-exts Exp tree, however it turns out to be surprisingly nontrivial, so I can't help wondering - is there an established easy-to-use library solution for this kind of source conversion? Ideally, it should integrate with haskell-src-exts.

Comment: You may find the [bound](https://github.com/ekmett/bound/) library by ekmett helpful

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the problems where the "Scrap Your Boilerplate" style generic libraries shine!

The one I'm most familiar with is [the `uniplate` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate), but I don't actually have it installed at the moment, so I'll use the (very similar) functionality found in [the `lens` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens). The idea here is that it uses `Data.Data.Data` (which is the best qualified name ever) and related classes to perform generic operations in a polymorphic way.

Here's the simplest possible example:

```
alphaConvert :: Module -> Module
alphaConvert = template %~ changeName

changeName :: Name -> Name
changeName (Ident n) = Ident $ n ++ "_conv"
changeName n = n
```

The `(%~)` operator is from `lens` and just means to to apply the function `changeName` to everything selected by the generic traversal `template`. So what this does is find every alphanumeric identifier and append `_conv` to it. Running this program on its own source produces this:

```
module AlphaConv where
import Language.Haskell.Exts
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Plated
import Data.Data.Lens

instance Plated_conv Module_conv
main_conv
  = do ParseOk_conv md_conv <- parseFile_conv "AlphaConv.hs"
       putStrLn_conv $ prettyPrint_conv md_conv
       let md'_conv = alphaConvert_conv md_conv
       putStrLn_conv $ prettyPrint_conv md'_conv

alphaConvert_conv :: Module_conv -> Module_conv
alphaConvert_conv = template_conv %~ changeName_conv

changeName_conv :: Name_conv -> Name_conv
changeName_conv (Ident_conv n_conv)
  = Ident_conv $ n_conv ++ "_conv"
changeName_conv n_conv = n_conv
```

Not terribly useful since it doesn't distinguish between identifiers bound locally and those defined in an outside scope (such as being imported), but it demonstrates the basic idea.

`lens` may seem a bit intimidating (it has a lot more functionality than just this); you may find `uniplate` or another library more approachable.

The way you'd approach your actual problem would be a multi-part transformation that first selects the subexpressions you want to alpha-convert inside of, then uses a transformation on those to modify the names you want changed.

Comment: generics address one possible problem (working with an AST) but not another (determining alpha equivalence, capture-avoidance, etc).  I had interpreted the question as being more about the latter, for which there are a few libraries (`unbound`, `bound`), but I don't know if they can be easily applied to `haskell-src-exts`.

Comment: +1 for the nice write-up, however, I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. I'm not familiar with the libraries you mention, but what I'm really trying to avoid is not so much boilerplate but genuine logic (identifying bound vs. free names for the most part).